# Visualization and simulation tools for Windows Workflow Foundation

Tags: workflow-foundation

I'm looking for visualization/simulation tools for Windows Workflow Foundation, which can show how certain data moves down the workflow and gets manipulated until the end result is reached. This is a bit similar to some IBM Rational modeling tools for Websphere.

Can someone recommend a product (preferably free, but commercial products are an option) and point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741706.aspx) from MSDN?

On a different option, full blown commercial product like K2 BlackPearl that is built on top of WF offer this type of capability albeit very costly.

Comment: Jimmy, thanks for pointing me to that example. :)

Answer (score 2):

A friend pointed me to the [Workflow Simulator on MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/workflowsimulator), and it works great.

It's also free and open source (under the MS-Public License).

Any other suggestions guys?

Comment: +1 for "nice!" factor, even though it's your question.